# Andengine setText unexpected behaviour in android 2.3.3

Tags: text, andengine, android-version

I have this code:

```
score = new Text(20, 50, font, "0123456789.()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", vbom);
```

score.setText("");
    scene.attachChild(score);

I read in internet, that in beginning of using Text, need to list all chars which will be used.

In my Galaxy S2 (android 4.0.3) this code works properly it is nothing on the scene,
but in my wife's Galaxy S2 (android 2.3.3) the result on scene is like this:

```
0123456789.()nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

It is problem of android version? Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

EDIT:

one more clue, if I use `score.setText("a");` instead of `score.setText("");`
than output is "a"

strange behaviour...

Comment: maybe reason is that GLES2 requires 15 API Level, but my project is 8 API Level. And my wife's phone has 2.3.3, what is less than 4.0.3. If my guess is correct, is there some workaround?

Comment: I can't reach my code now, but I will try this: `score.setText("/n");`
I will let you know later.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but why you said "using text need to list all chars which will be used"? This is not true in GLES2, however you need to specific the maximum characters your text will use.

Comment: what do you mean "is not true in GLES2"? maybe something is wrong with my english, sorry, if so, but I think, that what I said is the same thing as you said.. "need to list characters" or "need to specify characters", if I won't specify, for example numbers, I will not be able to setText("124"); if I wrong, you can correct me.

Comment: and I read, that in GLES1 was ChangeableText, but in GLES2 it is Text. http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/changable-text-in-gles2-t7332.html - "The normal Text class in GLES2 is equivalent with the ChangeableText class in GLES1."

Comment: You also don't need to specific the the maximum chars but if you don't, it will use the length of the initial text. So, if you initialize with a string and set a bigger one later, it will throw an overflow exception.

Comment: `score = new Text(20, 50, gameController.textures.getFont(), 
          "0123456789.()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", GameController.vbom);
        score.setText("_");
        scene.attachChild(score);` and after this, I can set text whichever I want and it's changes. It's working at least on 4.0.3 and 2.3.3. You can test this on other devices and give feedback.

Comment: Seems we can use that symbol which is not present in font file!

Answer (score 1):

The Text class in AndEngine is picky. If you want to change the text after you create the object you have to specify the length of the string in the constructor (notice the `.length()`):

```
Text score = new Text(20, 50, font, "test", "test".length(), vbom);
```

If you use it like this:

```
Text score = new Text(20, 50, font, "test", vbom);
```

Then I think the text will not change, even after using `setText("foo");`

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical problem. I had the same problem in my game. A would advice you just to hide the text(or detach it and attach it if required later).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid delays in a game you should use

```
mFont.prepareLetters("0123456789".toCharArray());
```

It will allocate memory and load characters.